# Date component in c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a component in my c# application that provide string like these:

```
"2020/1/1"
"2012/2/12"
```

But I want to change theme to these format:

```
"2020/01/01"
"2012/02/12"
```

Comment: You'll need to format them with yyyy/MM/dd then. If you can't access them as a date (the component gives you a string) then you'll need to parse them as yyyy/M/d then ToString them as yyyy/MM/dd. You could also do it all stringly, Split('/') and pad the second and third elements with PadLeft

Comment: Please show us what you tried then we show you were you failed and how to fix it.

Comment: Don't spam irrelevant tags, that will only put people of.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check the answer?If you have any other questions, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this approach is simple enough for your convenience :

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("2020/1/1").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    }
}
```